# Magento 2 override magento sales core model for pdf invoice not working

Tags: magento2

I am overriding Magento_sales core pdf file like following:

[image]

In di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf" type="Mobistore\Modulesales\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf" />
</config>
```

IN module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Mobistore_Modulesales" setup_version="1.0.1">
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
</sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

In invoice.pdf

```
<?php
  /**
    * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
    * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 namespace Mobistore\Modulesales\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf;

/**
* Sales Order Invoice PDF model
* @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{

 public function getPdf($invoices = [])
 {
    $this->_beforeGetPdf();
    $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $this->_setPdf($pdf);
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

    foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
            $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
        }
        $page = $this->newPage();
        $order = $invoice->getOrder();
        /* Add image */
        $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add address */
        $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
        /* Add head */
        $this->insertOrder(
            $page,
            $order,
            $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                $order->getStoreId()
            )
        );
        /* Add document text and number */
        $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
        /* Add table */
        $this->_drawHeader($page);
        /* Add body */
        foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
        /* Add totals */
        $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
        if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
            $this->_localeResolver->revert();
        }

    }


    foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
            continue;
        }
        $sku                =   $item->getSku();

        $objectManager      =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $id                 =   $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($sku);
        $product            =   $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
        $refurbComment      =   $product->getRefurbComment();
        $is_refurb          =   $product->getAttributeText('is_refurb');
        if($is_refurb=='Yes'){
            $this->insertConditions($page,$refurbComment);
        }

    }


    $this->_afterGetPdf();
    return $pdf;
}


public function insertConditions($page,$comment)
{
    $this->y -= 25;
    $page->drawText($comment, 35, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
}   


}
```

But it is still running the core model file

I made changes in the **getPdf()** function but not working

I run these command also number of times:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magenticians_Moduleproduct
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I followed this tutorial on how to extend MODEL files

https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/

Any help in letting me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Update your preference of di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Mobistore\Modulesales\Model\Sales\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

Then after check.